# Create .PNG images in Python from MatLab data

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

Actually i'm trying to create .png images in Python. The data is get from a Matlab file. 
Here my code. When i running i have the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readFromMatLab.py", line 20, in 
    matriz[x][y][z] = data[x][y][z]
IndexError: list index out of range

The data of the Matlab file is 512x512x200 Double array.

```
> {'__version__': '1.0', 'St3D': array([[[ -4.98510788e-02, 
> -4.98139346e-02,  -4.97636073e-02, ...,
>           -5.19862428e-02,  -5.20095813e-02,  -5.20122990e-02],
>         [ -4.98249255e-02,  -4.97792210e-02,  -4.97507640e-02, ...,
>           -5.19832396e-02,  -5.19884452e-02,  -5.20089354e-02],
>         [ -4.98121755e-02,  -4.97751679e-02,  -4.97488529e-02, ...,
>           -5.19605824e-02,  -5.19734534e-02,  -5.20023879e-02],
>         ...,
>        [[  9.10799464e-05,   1.75287655e-04,   2.26928715e-04, ...,
>            1.10619951e-04,   1.04038395e-04,   7.44506576e-05],
>         [  6.29097917e-05,   1.20765020e-04,   1.91577341e-04, ...,
>            8.24078623e-05,   8.96774520e-05,   7.44268856e-05],
>         [  4.14273859e-05,   7.96562916e-05,   1.20801256e-04, ...,
>            9.05750282e-05,   8.13201896e-05,   6.77554603e-05],
>         ..., 
>         [  1.72297366e-04,   1.68849830e-04,   2.21771692e-04, ...,
>            2.30046391e-04,   2.51247428e-04,   2.58021432e-04],
>         [  2.06350049e-04,   1.92126121e-04,   2.58923928e-04, ...,
>            2.48977658e-04,   2.78131275e-04,   2.76242136e-04],
>         [  2.42915268e-04,   2.47607632e-04,   2.89283796e-04, ...,
>            2.58819021e-04,   2.76203977e-04,   2.82977241e-04]]]), '__header__': 'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Fri
> Sep 19 17:03:17 2014', '__globals__': []}


#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pprint
import scipy.io
import numpy
from scipy import misc
from PIL import Image

# import file into a dictionary
fMatLab = scipy.io.loadmat('St3D', mat_dtype = True, squeeze_me = True, struct_as_record=False)

# read in the structure
data = fMatLab['St3D']

matriz = [[[0 for col in range(data.shape[0])] for row in range(data.shape[1])] for x in range(data.shape[2])]

for x in range(0,data.shape[0]):
    for y in range(0,data.shape[1]):
        for z in range(0,data.shape[2]):
            matriz[x][y][z] = data[x][y][z]

for i in range(len(matriz)):
    #im = numpy.random.random_integers(0, 255, 512*512).reshape((512, 512))
    misc.imsave('transect_%s.png' % i, matriz[i])

from glob import glob
filelist = glob('transect*.png')
filelist.sort()
```

Comment: You probably wanted `matriz = data.transpose((2,1,0))`, and no loop or triple-comprehension; but why do this at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are trying to apply `misc.imsave` to each slice along a certain dimension of your data. However, the code is very inefficient, especially from `matriz =` to `matriz[x][y][z] =`. You already have the matrix stored as a numpy array in the variable `data`, so there is no need for the list comprehension or the loops. If you want to loop over slices of a numpy array across one dimension, say, for example, the third dimension, to apply a function, just do something like this:

```
for i in xrange(data.shape[2]):
    some_function(data[:, :, i])
```

**EDIT**
In your case, this would translate to

```
data = fMatLab['St3D']
for i in xrange(data.shape[2]):
    misc.imsave('transect_%s.png' % i, data[:, :, i])
```

And, as a quick final note, the last three lines shouldn't be indented.

Comment: you try to say: `data = fMatLab['St3D'] for i in range(2): misc.imsave('transect_%s.png' % i, data[:,:,i] )`

Comment: Yes, but use `data.shape[2]`, not just '2' (see edit). You want to loop over the entire third dimension. Try typing `data.shape` to see what I mean, or check the [numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html).

Comment: its works for me. Now i need obtain one image with quality and optimize the process. Do you know how obtain a faster solution? I testing the code with `img = scipy.misc.toimage(data[:,:,i], mode='I')` but the images are complety black. Thanks

Comment: I'd be happy to think about it. The best option would be to, first, since my answer worked for you, accept and upvote it, and second, start a new question about increasing performance. If you put a link to it in the comments here, I'll check it out.

Comment: Thanks it works for me. You response give me the solution for my question.

Comment: You actually accept the answer, not by writing it in the comments, but by clicking on the checkmark under the arrows to the left of the top of my answers. To upvote, click on the one of those two arrows pointing up. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for details.

Comment: Thanks philE. the new question is on the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046730/increasing-performance-when-create-png-images-in-python-from-matlab-data