# Increasing performance when create .PNG images in Python from MatLab data

Tags: python, image, performance, matlab

Actually i'm trying to create .png images in Python. The data is get from a Matlab file. 
The solution of code was presented on the question :

[Create .PNG images in Python from MatLab data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025308/create-png-images-in-python-from-matlab-data)

The code works but i'm trying have images with better quality and optimize the process to create the images. Do you know how obtain a faster solution with quality? I testing the code with `img = scipy.misc.toimage(data[:,:,i], mode='I')` but the images are complety black. For the optimization i don't have idea. Thanks

The code is here:

```
!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scipy.io
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
from glob import glob

# import file into a dictionary
fMatLab = scipy.io.loadmat('St3D', mat_dtype = True, squeeze_me = True, struct_as_record=False)

# read in the structure
data = fMatLab['St3D']
for i in range(data.shape[2]):
    misc.imsave('image_%s.png' % i, data[:,:,i] )
```

EDIT: It's works for me

```
def saveImages(data, fileName):
    img = scipy.misc.toimage(data, low=0, high=255, mode='P')    
    img.save(fileName)
    return img

imP = saveImages(data[i,:,:], 'image_%s.png' % i)
```

Comment: [Profile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) your code to see where it is slow, try to optimize that, and if that fails ask a more targeted question.

Comment: *but the images are complety black* -- what is the dtype of the mat you're loading and what are the values (min/max) in the matrices `data[:,:,i]`?

Comment: the images aren't black. I solved with this code: img = scipy.misc.toimage(data[:,:,i], high=255, low=-0, mode='P')
        img.save('at_%s.png' % i)

Comment: I actualize my question with the solution